# Quickblox Change Camera and Record Video Chat

Tags: android, quickblox

I am using QuickBlox Video Chat Sample and it is working fine. Now I want to use back camera and Documentation says that camera can be changed during video call by using cameraView.switchCamera() . But I dont know where should I put this code . Also Documentation says that Video Chat can be recorded , so I want to know that how can I record Video chat and can access later.

Answer (score 3):

1 - To switch camera you could use cameraView.switchCamera() 
For example, You can locate switch button over cameraView in xml file ,apply clickListener for it:

```
switchCameraBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cameraView.switchCamera();
            }
});
```

2 - You can handle all data that coming from camera and your opponent in this callBack:

```
private OnQBVideoChatListener qbVideoChatListener = new OnQBVideoChatListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCameraDataReceive(byte[] videoData) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onMicrophoneDataReceive(byte[] audioData) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onOpponentVideoDataReceive(byte[] videoData) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onOpponentAudioDataReceive(byte[] audioData) {
        }

    };
```

Comment: Added a button to change Camera during call but it doesn't change camera , though app got hanged. For creating video from byte array, can you provide me any sample code.

Comment: @Andrew Dmytrenko I could not find this class in Quickblox you have used. how you have done can you please explain a bit more!

Comment: @Shishram i left QuickBlox almost 2 years ago. Probably quickblox team completely changed android sdk api so please check official documentation on their website.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewDmytrenko but one quick thing was this video recording there earlier when you were working there, because right now I couldn't find video recording in current SDK. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Shishram Youre welcome.
No audio or video recording out of the box, in the past you just had access to raw audio/video data that your phone record or receive from opponent

Comment: Thanks again man @AndrewDmytrenko I am also in need of the byte[] but its not there in Github code of latest sdk still i have created an issue asking the same question.